# Does iOS purge disk usage in the document directory?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I could not find a limitation on the amount of disk space an iOS app can consume in its document directory, other than what's actually available on the phone's disk.

1. Does this mean that an app can use 100GB of document directory space if the phone has it available?
2. If another app needs space but doesn't have any to use because of this resource-hogging app, does iOS purge the disk space of abusers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the docs that explain about the various options for storing data here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Specifically, check out `Table 1-1  Commonly used directories of an iOS app` which should answer all your questions.

1. There is no limit on the amount of data you can store there, other than the on-device storage available.

   However, the documents directory is only to be used for "user-generated content". It will be backed up to iCloud, so it's just for files the user would expect to be backed up. If the review team think you are using it to store support files that should be in the `temp` directory (which the system does purge when low on space), your app will fail review.

   The `The iCloud File Storage Container` section goes into specifics about the kind of thing that is considered user data:

   "Documents that the user creates and sees in an app's user interface—for example the document browsers in Pages, Numbers, and Keynote should be stored in the Documents directory. Another example of files that might go in the Documents directory are saved games, again because they are something that an app could potentially provide some sort of method for selecting.

   Anything that the app does not want the user to see or modify directly should be placed outside of the Documents directory.  Apps can create any subdirectories inside the container directory, so they can arrange private files as desired."
2. The contents of the Documents directory are not purged by the system when low on space.

Comment: The link was a great resource. Do we know how frequently the `tmp` folder is purged for iOS apps? I've read that on macOS it can be any files that aren't accessed in three days.

Comment: As far as I know there's no documentation on that (it could happen at any time). The `tmp` folder is for data that doesn't need to persist between app launches - if you expect data to be there the next time the user launches the app, then don't put it in there. If you want to store data that persists between app launches you can use the `Library` folder. I believe anything in the `Library` folder won't be cleaned up by the system in a low storage situation. Just be aware that it is backed up to iCloud, so you may want to exclude files from backup where it makes sense.